# Meet two generic values in one function

Tags: c++, templates

I have two callbacks `foo` and `bar`, both taking a generic value each.
When both callbacks has been called I want these values to meet in single function. My test code is:

```cpp
template <class FooType, class BarType>
void meet_point(FooType foo_value, BarType bar_value) {
    // Success
}

struct test
{
    template <class FooType>
    void foo(FooType value) {
        // TODO: save value or type somehow
    }

    template <class BarType>
    void bar(BarType value) {
        meet_point(/* FooType value from above */, value);
    }
};

template <class F>
void sync_request(F&& f) {
    f("foobar");
}

int main()
{
    test t;

    sync_request([&t](auto value) {
        t.foo(value);
    });

    t.bar(42);
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

**EDIT:**

Note that code in `main()` is just an example of calling both callbacks. Actual calls happens from different places and both triggers do not know anything about each other.

Also at the time of instantiating `test` object no type is known ahead. Actually `test` struct is not even needed here. It could be standalone callbacks. It is there just for maybe possible storage of `FooType` value.

**P.S.**

I wish we had [reflection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/reflect), [jit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3ov8HcdVKw), [Circle @type_id](https://github.com/QuantlabFinancial/cpp_tip_of_the_week/blob/master/239.md) or templated virtual functions to extract the type in C++.

Comment: Unless you have a full list of types you call at least one of the functions with, and you can enumerate them all in one place, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Do you know `FooType` when you create the `test` object?

Comment: @mch Unfortunately no, I dont. Code in `main()` is just an example. Actual call to `foo` and `bar` happens from different places.

Comment: You can store it in an `std::any` and use an `enum` to remember the type. Then you can make a `std::anycast` on the variable depending on the `enum`.

Comment: do you know the type of foo and bar when you create the first callback?

Comment: @mch It could work if types was limited to a small range of types. But both types can be anything in my case.

Comment: @KoronisNeilos Nope, I don't.

Comment: @mch you are describing `std::variant` there. If both types can be *anything*, there are *infinite* cases in your enum.

Comment: "both types can be anything" Then there is no way.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Never say never ;)

Comment: @Caleth I thought about https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/type and that's solved with `std::any`, but does not work if you don't have a list of types. This unsolvable c++ problem is so trivial in python...

Comment: @mch yes, you can put (almost) anything in `std::any`. The trick is getting it back out. That's the thing with static types: you have to know what they are

Comment: You should rethink your requirements. While you do not know what types your user will crate when you write your code. The types has to be known at compile time so you could give your user something to register his types. Which you can use in your code.

Comment: Are you fine with allow the user to register his types? I have a solution if this is possible.

Comment: @KoronisNeilos Yes please, post your solution. It may be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know (or be able to exhaustively list the possibilities of) at least one of `FooType` or `BarType`.

Case 1: `FooType` is one of `typename... FooTypes` known when you instantiate a `test`.

```
template<typename... FooTypes>
struct test
{
    using FooType = std::variant<FooTypes...>;

    void foo(FooType value) {
        foo_value = value;
    }

    template <class BarType>
    void bar(BarType value) {
        std::variant<BarType> bar_value = value;
        std::visit(meet_point, foo_value, bar_value);
    }

    FooType foo_value;
};
```

Case 2: `BarType` is one of `typename... BarTypes` known when you instantiate a `test`.

```
template<typename... BarTypes>
struct test
{
    using BarType = std::variant<BarTypes...>;

    template <class FooType>
    void foo(FooType value) {
        std::variant<FooType> foo_value = value;
        visit = [foo_value](BarType bar_value){ std::visit(meet_point, foo_value, bar_value); };
    }

    void bar(BarType value) {
        visit(value)
    }

    function<void(std::variant<BarTypes...>)> visit;
};
```

Case 3: `FooType` is one of `typename... FooTypes` *and* `BarType` is one of `typename... BarTypes`, both known when you instantiate a `test`.

```
template<typename... FooTypes, typename... BarTypes>
struct test
{
    using FooType = std::variant<FooTypes...>;
    using BarType = std::variant<BarTypes...>;

    void foo(FooType value) {
        foo_value = value;
    }

    void bar(BarType bar_value) {
        std::visit(meet_point, foo_value, bar_value);
    }

    std::variant<FooTypes...> foo_value;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but no type is known ahead. That's the problem.

Comment: @VladimirTalybin: Think of it this way: to solve this, the compiler would need to either (A) generate `meet_point` for every possible combination of types, or (B) be able to generate new `meet_point` bytecode mid-execution. C++ is capable of neither of these things, so this is not a solvable problem. You need to rethink your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

When you write your code you do not know which types the user of your library will use. But when the user compiles his types has to be known. If you are fine with letting the user register his types you can do it like this:

```cpp
#include <boost/algorithm/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// code you write
struct CallbackData
{
  virtual ~CallbackData () = default;
};
// code your user writes for example in userTypes.h
struct TestFooType : CallbackData
{
  int value = 42;
};
struct TestBarType : CallbackData
{
  std::string value{ "bar type" };
};

struct AnotherTestFooType : CallbackData
{
  int value = 42;
};
struct AnotherTestBarType : CallbackData
{
  std::string value{ "bar type" };
};

static boost::hana::tuple<TestFooType, TestBarType, AnotherTestFooType, AnotherTestBarType> const sharedClasses{};

// code you write
struct test
{
  void
  bothAreReady ()
  {
    boost::hana::for_each (sharedClasses, [&] (auto x) {
      if (std::shared_ptr<std::decay_t<decltype (x)>> firstValue = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<std::decay_t<decltype (x)>> (fooValue))
        {
          std::cout << "fooValue: " << firstValue->value << std::endl;
          return;
        }
    });
    boost::hana::for_each (sharedClasses, [&] (auto x) {
      if (std::shared_ptr<std::decay_t<decltype (x)>> secondValue = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<std::decay_t<decltype (x)>> (barValue))
        {
          std::cout << "barValue: " << secondValue->value << std::endl;
          return;
        }
    });
  }
  bool
  isDone ()
  {
    return fooValue && barValue;
  }
  std::shared_ptr<CallbackData> fooValue{};
  std::shared_ptr<CallbackData> barValue{};
};

// code your user writes
int
main ()
{
  test t;
  auto fooAction = [&t] () {
    auto testFooType = TestFooType{};
    // do something with test foo type
    t.fooValue = std::shared_ptr<CallbackData>{ new std::decay_t<decltype (testFooType)>{ std::move (testFooType) } };
    if (t.isDone ()) t.bothAreReady ();
  };

  auto barAction = [&t] () {
    auto testBarType = TestBarType{};
    // do something with testBarType
    t.barValue = std::shared_ptr<CallbackData>{ new std::decay_t<decltype (testBarType)>{ std::move (testBarType) } };
    if (t.isDone ()) t.bothAreReady ();
  };
  // run the lambdas on some other thread or so
  fooAction ();
  barAction ();
}
```

[wandbox example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rUtCms2Uhft7icXX)

Comment: Ok nice, but still it require types (listed in `sharedClasses`) to be known ahead for `dynamic_cast` later.

Comment: I just thought you mean register types like in [std::any::type example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/type). Not ahead, but at any time. Sorry for misunderstanding...

Answer (score 0):

Alice live in Australia. Alice creates a nice class `Alice`, writes a source file that contains a call to `test.foo(Alice())`, builds a DLL, and ships it to you.

Bob lives in Bermuda. Bob creates a nice class `Bob`, writes a source file that contains a call to `test.bar(Bob())`, builds a DLL, and ships it to you.

Alice and Bob have never heard of each other and have never seen each other's code.

You have your program load the two DLLs and...

Where is `meet_point<Alice, Bob>`?

It cannot be in Alice's DLL, because Alice have never seen Bob's code.

It cannot be in Bob's DLL, because Bob have never seen Alice's code.

It cannot be in your program, because you have never seen the code of either of them! All you have is their DLL that call *your* code. They both obviously have your header that defines `struct test`, but this doesn't help at all.

So you need some tool that would go over Alice's and Bob's code, extract all types that are used in calls to `foo` and `bar`, and instantiate `meet_point<a, b>` with every possible pair (a, b) of such types. The problem is, there isn't such tool in any standard toolkit. You need to write one somehow.

The easiest way would be asking Alice and Bob to send you a list of their types used in calls to `foo` and `bar`. You can also go over their object code and extract these types from symbols or whatever. In any case you need them to send you header files with definitions of all their classes, so that you can compile each instantiation. Another option (not as crazy as it sounds) would be just-in-time compilation: make your class find the headers (you can know the *names* of the classes so that's doable), generate a source that instantiates `meet_point` with relevant arguments, run the compiler, build a DLL, load it, and call the function! Cache the DLL for later use. Of course it could happen that `meet_point` cannot be compiled with a particular combination of arguments, and you will only know it when this combination arrives.

Now "two developers that do not talk to each other send you DLLs" is an extreme model of the situation, but it doesn't actually create any new problem. It just makes it easier to see problems that are inherent in the situation.

Comment: Actually it can be done will stateful meta programming. But it is against standard and I guess any solution to this will be "fixed" by C++ committee to remain the language strong typed.